# Converting string representation of last modification time back to its type(std::filesystem::file_time_type)

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I have made a function, that uses the C++ [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) module to get the last modification time of a given file, converting it to a **std::string**.

```
std::string Helper::lastWriteTime(const std::string& itemName)
{
    std::filesystem::path file(itemName);
    auto time = std::filesystem::last_write_time(file);

    std::time_t cftime = decltype(time)::clock::to_time_t(time);

    return std::to_string(cftime);
}
```

However, now I want to use this string and use it as a parameter for another method - which converts the string and changes the last modification time according to the string representation. The reverse order of the methods didn´t work, is there a way to achieve it?

For receiving the last modification time of file I use function [std::filesystem::last_write_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) that works with data type [std::filesystem::file_time_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_time_type).

*Background: String interpretation is needed because I send these data via the network and then after receiving this time I use it and change last modification time of another file so they have same times.*

Example output of the **lastWriteTime** method: 
**1568045082**

Comment: Is the question - how do you convert a string holding an integer into a `file_time_type`?

Comment: Basically, yes. Is my question title inappropriate? I thought its better this way, but can change it.

Comment: Odds are pretty good that you can't do it portably, because the variable `time` in your example is some implementation-specific chrono time point, and without the  type information there, it will be hard to get back.

Comment: Especially if you are attempting the reconstruction on a different system.

Comment: It'll be easier in C++20 with clock casts and `to_stream`/`from_stream` support.

Comment: Well, I heard that they will make the work with times easier in C++20, however hoped that I missed the solution and there is a work around hidden somewhere. The portability is also a problem, for example if I decide to host one point of the connection on Linux and the other point will be on windows. Probably will need to rethink the whole approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until C++20's full date/time stuff comes along, there isn't much you can do with a `file_time_type` besides store it and compare it to another `file_time_type`. Your `to_time_t` trick is not portable, because `file_time_type` is *not* required to be a `system_clock` time.

If you want to store a string representing an integer representation of a `file_time_type` and convert it back, then you should just get the `time_since_epoch().count()` of the time directly, rather than using `to_time_t` gymnastics. You can convert the integer back to a `file_time_type` by doing this:

```
unsigned long long int_val = ...;
using ft = std::filesystem::file_time_type;
auto the_time = ft(ft::duration(int_val));
```

Of course, this only works if the source and destination implementations use compatible filesystem clocks. And even if they use the same clocks with the same epochs, their `file_time_type::duration` needs to be the same too.

Comment: I agree this is the best approach until C++20 is available.  One thing to be careful about with this approach is that you have to ensure that `ft::duration::period` is the same type on both ends of this conversion.  I.e. if one machine sends this string to another machine over the network, both machines must agree that `ft::duration` is `nanoseconds` (or whatever unit).  Otherwise you've got a run-time error.

Comment: Thanks for good tip! Will give it a try! I´m little disappointed there is no easier way to handle this before C++20.

Comment: Little bit off -topic, about portability of this idea. As I understand, when I use these time structures/methods, do I lose the portability? I´m new to these time interface, so didn´t expect that even with the file_time_type I lose the same behaviour on different machines.

Comment: The epoch of `file_time_type`  is not (and will not be) specified.  And the epoch is likely to be 1970 with gcc and llvm, but 1601 on Windows.  Precision on gcc and llvm looks like nanoseconds, and on Windows 100ns.  I'm guessing at these numbers, they aren't set in stone at this time.  Once one knows the epoch and precision for a given platform, it is relatively simple to translate the epochs and precisions.  C++20 will automate that task.

Comment: Another way of dealing with the epoch difference is to use a string format that describes a time point in the civil calendar, instead of time duration since an epoch.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understood what is the answer since c++20 ?